# Why does Next.js pass static files as parameter to url?

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

First thing, I got Error: 
`Fetch API cannot load file:///xxxx/web-frontend/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.`

I couldn't decide why that happened. Then I saw in Python Backend API console this message:

```
[10/Dec/2019 14:24:54] "GET /api/main_get/boards/b/ HTTP/1.1" 500 17478
[10/Dec/2019 14:24:54] "GET /api/main_get/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87
[10/Dec/2019 14:24:54] "GET /api/main_get/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87
Not Found: /api/main_get/boards/_stream_readable.js/
Not Found: /api/main_get/boards/events.js/
[10/Dec/2019 14:24:54] "GET /api/main_get/boards/_stream_readable.js/ HTTP/1.1" 404 30
[10/Dec/2019 14:24:54] "GET /api/main_get/boards/events.js/ HTTP/1.1" 404 30
```

Then I decided to log params in Node.js console. I got:

```
{ abbr: 'b' }
{ abbr: 'events.js' }
{ abbr: '_stream_readable.js' }
```

My frontend server set-up:

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

const port = +process.env.PORT || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();

    server.get('/boards/:abbr', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.params);
        return app.render(req, res, '/boards', { abbr : req.params.abbr });
    })

    server.all('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.listen(port, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}!`);
    })
});
```

Why does Express/Next.js server recognize files as "abbr" parameter?

Comment: [My board page](https://github.com/Lebed-kun/imageboard/blob/master/web-frontend/pages/boards.js)

Comment: This issue happaned due to `getInitialProps` is triggered many times at one page load. But why this method is called multiple times but not once?

Comment: are you getting a correct expected result here https://github.com/Lebed-kun/imageboard/blob/master/web-frontend/pages/index.js#L39? I would speculate that it renders links with incorrect urls here `/boards/${el.abbr}`, which get preloaded. Does your api serve data with correct content type?

Comment: Yup. What does the API have to do with it? The problem is that Node.js server tries to get static files through same dynamic uri which is used to get page contents, passing filename to "abbr" paramater. When I try to get "localhost:3000/boards/b"

Comment: That error is caused by API. I manually created threads in DB but forgot to assign them first post.

Answer (score 0):

That error is caused by API. I manually created threads in DB but forgot to assign them first post.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue but I don't understand this solution. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Turned out i was grabbing the wrong attribute from ctx object passed into getInitialProps (I was using ctx.req.query instead of ctx.query)